# Outlook 2016 Calendar Event Sync Issue

Tags: windows, exchange, outlook, microsoft-office, calendar

I am working on an issue with Outlook 2016. User A has full mailbox rights and calendar ownership rights of User B's calendar. User A manages the calendar events for User B and also invites other users to collaborate on managing the calendar with similar ownership rights. When User A updates a calendar event on User B's calendar (e.g., changing the time of a specific event) the calendar does not update.

Additionally, calendar events that are created (by User A on User B's calendar) as an All-Day event spanning multiple days display properly in the header of that calendar day in the Outlook 2016 desktop application but on mobile devices (iPhones synced to Exchange Servers via VMWare Intelligent Hub) the All-Day event blocks off entire days instead of showing in only the header.

I am consulting with our Exchange team that works on the Exchange servers but was wondering if either of these issues sounded familiar and if there is anything that can be done on the user's end to resolve. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, can you test an iPhone in simeple ActiveSync mode to see if it work good ?